# Translating F# function partial application to C#

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming

I'm translating this [F# source](https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/master/src/Chessie/ErrorHandling.fs) for railway oriented programming [to C#](https://github.com/gsscoder/railwaysharp/blob/master/src/RailwaySharp/ErrorHandling.cs).

I'm having trouble translating this `SelectMany` overload:

```
  static member inline SelectMany (this:Result<'TSuccess, 'TMessage>, func: Func<_,_>, mapper: Func<_,_,_>) =
    let mapper = lift2 (fun a b -> mapper.Invoke(a,b))
    let v = bind func.Invoke this
    mapper this v
```

I've mapped function signature with the above:

```
  public static Result<TResult, TMessage> SelectMany<TSuccess, TMessage, TValue, TResult>(
    this Result<TSuccess, TMessage> result,
    Func<TSuccess, Result<TValue, TMessage>> func,
    Func<TSuccess, TValue, TResult> mapperFunc)
```

F# `lift2` function (that I think I've correctly [translated](https://github.com/gsscoder/railwaysharp/blob/master/src/RailwaySharp/ErrorHandling.cs#L626)) accepts as first parameter a function with signature `('a -> 'b -> 'c)`, but when bound to `mapper` let-binding with partial application I've problem understanding the used lambda function.

I normally use [these helpers](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/609a95695fb5ec0875dc) for partial application, but I was not able to translate this F# code to C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Lift2 is expecting a curried function, but the mapper passed into SelectMany is not curried.  So let's curry it:

```
Func<TSuccess, Func<TValue, TResult>> curriedMapper = suc => val => mapperFunc(suc, val);
Func<
    Result<TSuccess, TMessage>, 
    Result<TValue, TMessage>, 
    Result<TResult, TMessage>
> liftedMapper = (a, b) => Lift2(curriedMapper, a, b);
var v = Bind(func, result);
return liftedMapper(result, v);
```

Comment: exactly what I was trying to do... So the first was a curried function and the second a partial application, right?

Comment: Yes.  The C# version doesn't technically have to partially apply Lift2 to get liftedMapper; it could just return Lift2(curriedMapper, result, Bind(func, result)) as in @scrwtp 's answer; that would also avoid its gnarly type declaration.  I was just translating line-for-line.

Comment: thanks this helped me to understand where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

In general, `lift2` takes a function of two arguments of simple types `'a` and `'b` and produces a function that works on wrapped types `M<'a>` and `M<'b>`. Otherwise, you can think of it as taking three arguments: a function over simple types and two wrapped values, unwrapping those values, applying the function to them and wrapping the result.

Assuming your functions were correctly ported from F#, the body of `SelectMany` would look like this:

```
return Lift2(mapper, this, Bind(func, this));
```

The odd `Invokes` are there in F# version, because `Funcs` are not applicable like in C#, you have to explicitly call `Invoke`. Also since it's uncurried, a `mapper.Invoke` can't be passed straight into `lift2` - that's why it's wrapped in a curried function.

Comment: I've provided a link with line number to check if `Trial.Lift2` was correctly ported from **F#** (see question).  `mapperFunc` signature is not compatible with the `func` accepted by `Lift2`. This was my primary issue...

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to not have it partially applied in the C# version. Partial application in F# is good, because it's built into the language. In C# it only serves to increase the noise.

Comment: @scrtp Do you mean without Lift2? How would you implement that?

Comment: See the first paragraph of my answer. You don't need to have a partially applied `lift2`. It's just a natural way to think about it in an FP language (a function that takes a function and returns a lifted function). You can just as well make it a function of three arguments, that takes a function, lifts it and applies it in one go.